# Spilt water on laptop, stuck on BIOS screen

Tags: laptop-repair, bootrepair

Friend spilt water on laptop, left it to dry for 7 hours and turned it back on. Now stuck on American Megatrends BIOS screen. What should he do?

Comment: 7 hours isn't enough. First thing you need to do in such situation - it is unplug it from power supply and remove battery as soon as possible, then disassemble a case and keep it under fan at least 3 days before trying to power it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FleetCommand is generally correct. However, if you have DIY skills and want to try it yourself:

1. Turn it off
2. Let it dry some more, maybe with a fan blowing on it to increase air circulation
3. Let it dry like that for at least 24 hours, maybe even 48.
4. Try it again

If it still fails... the most likely thing to have happened is that something got shorted in the keyboard. On a lot of larger (i.e. serviceable) laptops, the keyboard is an easily-swappable part and replacements are cheap and easy to find ($20-$40). if it's a Dell, they have complete service manuals online. If it's something else, look for service info both at the manufacturer's site and at places like iFixit and YouTube... or just do a Google search.

In any case, a quick test, if you can find out how to remove the keyboard, is to try it without the keyboard connected. If the problem is indeed in the keyboard the machine should boot ok (but of course you won't be able to type), but at least this will tell you the rest of the machine is ok.

If it isn't, then your friend is probably in for a new keyboard AND motherboard.

If it's a machine that can't be disassembled with screws, but is held together with adhesive tape and must be pried apart... forget it. Take it to a service place or throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

Take it to an authorized repair center ASAP.

This is clearly a hardware problem and hardware problems are NOT solvable over the Internet. Without a close inspection, it is impossible to say what is damaged.